# Listing revisions of wordpress posts/sites

Tags: wordpress

Everybody knows that in WordPress you can view all revisions of posts and sites... But how to list all revisions on this sites or posts with dates and links to preview this revision?
Is there any plugin to do that? I searched a lot, so I doubt it
Or maybe anybody has an example code...
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

**for admin management**
there should be a **revisions** block that shows each revision and is linked to view it. if this block is not showing on the edit post page, then at the very top right, there should be a **screen options** tab. click that, and check the revisions box. it should then show up on the page below, usually below the post content itself.

**for public access**
[here](http://www.wordyard.com/2010/08/03/change-is-good-but-show-your-work/) is an interesting writeup about public revisions and why that should be important. towards the bottom is a link to the plugin page

[here's another link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-show-post-updatesrevisions-to-your-readers-in-wordpress/) that may help, but the plugin may not be up-to-date

**custom php/sql**
if you know php and sql, you can extract all revisions from the database. there's a table called **wp_posts**. in that table, there's a **post_type** column. there you'll find various types of posts. **revisions** are the post types you're looking to query here. the **post_name** of a revision is the **post_parent** column followed by the revision version. you could write your own query with a plugin that allows you to insert raw php

Comment: Yes, you right. But I want to display on the front. I know that it is on the backend - I need to display it on the frontend